# Double border to a UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios

I have to display a UIButton like in the following image. Button size can be varying. How can I do that? Please suggest a way.

[image]

Comment: check this link may be this can help [link](http://nachbaur.com/blog/rendering-views-using-calayer-part-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a simple outline (it's a little hard to tell from your image what the button is), create the button with `UIButtonTypeCustom` (so you get a blank slate) then set its background color to be black. next, get the [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) of the button (through the [layer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layer) method) and set the [borderColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/borderColor) and [borderWidth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/borderWidth) properties as desired.

Comment: Button needs a white border with a shadow of fluorescent blue color.

Answer (score 0):

make a view and set it's color a bit darker than your desired button color, then make a button a bit shorter than the view size and place it as your fit position, check n tell me if it helps youe

Comment: no good because you don't get the pressed state on the background view